# How to find if an array contains a specific string in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

Can someone tell me how to detect if `"specialword"` appears in an array? Example:

```
categories: [
    "specialword"
    "word1"
    "word2"
]
```

Comment: In pure JS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25765186/1320932

Comment: pure JS : categories.includes("specialword")

Comment: @patz watch out for pure JS, not supported in IE (any version) [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: @foxontherock start using transpiler - stop worrying about anything fact-checking, can-I-use-this-property kinda thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an array includes a value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1163, accepted):

You really don't need jQuery for this.

```
var myarr = ["I", "like", "turtles"];
var arraycontainsturtles = (myarr.indexOf("turtles") > -1);
```

> **Hint**: indexOf returns a number, representing the position where the specified searchvalue occurs for the first time, or -1 if it never
>   occurs

or

```
function arrayContains(needle, arrhaystack)
{
    return (arrhaystack.indexOf(needle) > -1);
}
```

It's worth noting that `array.indexOf(..)` is [not supported in IE < 9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Browser_compatibility), but jQuery's `indexOf(...)` function will work even for those older versions.

Comment: James, that page does say it will work in IE9, as I indicated. Did you get it work for IE < 9 ? I believe I've run into this feature as missing in IE7 and IE8, but did not actually test; instead I relied on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Browser_compatibility

Comment: indexOf is available in all major browsers, except IE < 9

Comment: what about `'foo' in arr`?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper: That checks for if an object key exists: `1 in ['a'] -> false` `1 in ['a', 'b'] -> true` `'length' in [] -> true` It just so happens in JS an array is essentially an object with numeric keys.

Comment: http://needsmorejquery.com

Comment: @James nice solution. I really like your use of "I like turtles". would be good for a split and join demo too.

Answer (score 693):

jQuery offers [`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray):

Note that inArray returns the index of the element found, so `0` indicates the element is the first in the array. `-1` indicates the element was not found.

```js
var categoriesPresent = ['word', 'word', 'specialword', 'word'];
var categoriesNotPresent = ['word', 'word', 'word'];

var foundPresent = $.inArray('specialword', categoriesPresent) > -1;
var foundNotPresent = $.inArray('specialword', categoriesNotPresent) > -1;

console.log(foundPresent, foundNotPresent); // true false
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

*Edit 3.5 years later*

`$.inArray` is effectively a wrapper for `Array.prototype.indexOf` in browsers that support it (almost all of them these days), while providing a shim in those that don't. It is essentially equivalent to adding a shim to `Array.prototype`, which is a more idiomatic/JSish way of doing things. MDN provides [such code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill). These days I would take this option, rather than using the jQuery wrapper.

```js
var categoriesPresent = ['word', 'word', 'specialword', 'word'];
var categoriesNotPresent = ['word', 'word', 'word'];

var foundPresent = categoriesPresent.indexOf('specialword') > -1;
var foundNotPresent = categoriesNotPresent.indexOf('specialword') > -1;

console.log(foundPresent, foundNotPresent); // true false
```

---

*Edit another 3 years later*

<sub>Gosh, 6.5 years?!</sub>

The best option for this in modern Javascript is `Array.prototype.includes`:

```
var found = categories.includes('specialword');
```

No comparisons and no confusing `-1` results. It does what we want: it returns `true` or `false`. For older browsers it's polyfillable [using the code at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Polyfill).

```js
var categoriesPresent = ['word', 'word', 'specialword', 'word'];
var categoriesNotPresent = ['word', 'word', 'word'];

var foundPresent = categoriesPresent.includes('specialword');
var foundNotPresent = categoriesNotPresent.includes('specialword');

console.log(foundPresent, foundNotPresent); // true false
```

Answer (score 39):

Here you go:

```
$.inArray('specialword', arr)
```

This function returns a positive integer (the array index of the given value), or `-1` if the given value was not found in the array.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/5Gdfc/

You probably want to use this like so:

```
if ( $.inArray('specialword', arr) > -1 ) {
    // the value is in the array
}
```

Answer (score 35):

we can use **includes** option (which is js built-in function), which will return true if the value is found else it will be false.

if you want the exact index you can use **indexOf** (which is also js built-in function), which will return the exact index if the value is found else it will return -1.

You can switch **.includes** with the **.some** method which returns a boolean.
It will exit as soon as a match was found, which is great for performance for huge arrays:

Note: all are case sensitive

```js
var myarr = ["I", "like", "turtles"];

isVal = myarr.includes('like')
index = myarr.indexOf('like')
some = myarr.some(item => item.toLowerCase() == 'like'.toLowerCase())


console.log(isVal)
console.log(index)
console.log(some)
```

please check this.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 17):

You can use a `for` loop:

```
var found = false;
for (var i = 0; i < categories.length && !found; i++) {
  if (categories[i] === "specialword") {
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I may be totally wrong on this, but wouldn't you want to declare i in the for loop? If you don't put "var" in front, it'll put it in the global context (I think...), which might not be what you want.

Comment: while that is true, that really isn't the point of what he is saying here. Don't ignore the forest for a few trees.

Comment: @ChrisJones Given that JS-amateurs will copy and paste this answer into their code, the better it should be

Comment: fwiw: you can now do something like: `const found = categories.any(c => c === "specialword");`

Answer (score 14):

## With modern javascript's Array methods:

***Array.prototype.includes()*** // introduced in ES7:

- returns boolean

```js
const data = {
  categories: [
    "specialword",
    "word1",
    "word2"
  ]
}

console.log("Array.prototype.includes()")
// Array.prototype.includes()
// returns boolean
console.log(data.categories.includes("specialword"))
console.log(data.categories.includes("non-exist"))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

***Array.prototype.find()*** // introduced in ES6:

- returns found element or undefined

```js
const data = {
  categories: [
    "specialword",
    "word1",
    "word2"
  ]
}

console.log("Array.prototype.find()")
// Array.prototype.find()
// returns the element if found
// returns undefined if not found
console.log(data.categories.find(el => el === "specialword") != undefined)
console.log(data.categories.find(el => el === "non-exist") != undefined)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't like `$.inArray(..)`, it's the kind of ugly, jQuery-ish solution that most sane people wouldn't tolerate. Here's a snippet which adds a simple `contains(str)` method to your arsenal:

```
$.fn.contains = function (target) {
  var result = null;
  $(this).each(function (index, item) {
    if (item === target) {
      result = item;
    }
  });
  return result ? result : false;
}
```

Similarly, you could wrap `$.inArray` in an extension:

```
$.fn.contains = function (target) {
  return ($.inArray(target, this) > -1);
}
```

Comment: (I'm not the downvoter) I'm not sure I understand the derision of $.inArray while wrapping up a method that relies on $(selector).each(). The actual inArray code simply uses indexOf for browsers that support it natively or a for loop like Jared's answer when it doesn't. Seems perfectly elegant to me.