# How to check if string has a matching substring by array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

## Problem

I know how to find out if a string contains a substring like this where you are looking for one word:

```
var s = "define foo";
alert(s.indexOf("define") > -1);
```

## But how could I check for multiple different words/substrings using an array?

Example not working code that makes sense in my mind but doesn't work:

```
query = "Define what is grape juice and how to drink it?"
var terms = ["define", "what is", "how to"];
alert(query.indexOf(terms) > -1);
```

Thanks~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.each()` in jQuery to iterate through the `terms` array, and check each of them individually against the string. In the code below, I create a new JSON object called `matchedTerms` that will log the term and its index in the string. See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/ktuuoprp/1/

```
var query = "Define what is grape juice and how to drink it?",
    terms = ["define", "what is", "how to"],
    matchedTerms = [];

$.each(terms, function(i,v) {
    var match = query.indexOf(v);
    matchedTerms.push({
        'term': v,
        'index': match
    });
});
```

Even better: you can build a conditional statement in there so that the `matchedTerms` will only produce a simple array. See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/ktuuoprp/2/

```
var query = "Define what is grape juice and how to drink it?",
    terms = ["define", "what is", "how to"],
    matchedTerms = [];

$.each(terms, function(i,v) {
    var match = query.indexOf(v);
    if(match > -1) matchedTerms.push(v);
});

console.log(matchedTerms);
```

p/s: If you want to perform case-insensitive matches, it helps to convert the query into lowercase, i.e. `newQuery = query.toLowerCase(query);`

Answer (score 2):

Try this out:

```
var phrase = 'texttexttexttexttexttexttext';
var terms = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3'];
function check(string) {
    var match = false;
    for(var i=0;i<terms.length && !match;i++) {
        if(string.indexOf(terms[i]) > -1) {
            match = true;
        }
    }
    return match;
}
//example
if(check(phrase)) {
    //iftrue
} else {
    //iffalse
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to see if an array includes a string.  There are a few ways to do it.  This is answered well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6116511/1026017).

Here are 2 options, copied from there:

**Option 1:**

`$.indexOf` is effectively a wrapper for `Array.prototype.indexOf` in browsers that support it (almost all of them these days), while providing a shim in those that don't. It is essentially equivalent to adding a shim to `Array.prototype`, which is a more idiomatic/JSish way of doing things. MDN provides [such code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill). These days I would take this option, rather than using the jQuery wrapper.

**Option 2:**

jQuery offers [`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray):

```
var found = $.inArray('specialword', categories) > -1;
```

Note that inArray returns the index of the element found, so `0` indicates the element is the first in the array. `-1` indicates the element was not found.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BWWRh/).

---

Comment: I think you've cited a reverse example — OP is asking for matching words in an array against a string to see if each element in the array exists or not.