# Find string in array using prototype functions

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
var str = "rrr";
var arr = ["ddd","rrr","ttt"];
```

I try to check If arr contains str. I try this:

```
  var res = arr .find(str);
```

But on row above is not works any idea what I do wrong?

Comment: What are you expecting in response ?

Comment: @Rayon no string exists I expect null if exists I expect true

Comment: Check `console` for errors... `Array#find` expects argument as `function`, not as `value`..

Comment: `arr.find( x => x === str );`

Comment: As per @Rayon: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: If, as per your comment, you want a `true` or `null` result depending on whether the item exists (as compared to getting back the index), maybe you should [edit] your question to mention that, because it opens up options like `.includes()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find if an array contains a specific string in JavaScript/jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116474/how-to-find-if-an-array-contains-a-specific-string-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Another time, please use a search engine to at least make an attempt at searching for an answer prior to asking a question.  The first result for a Google search for [Find string in array](https://www.google.com/search?q=Find+string+in+array) is a duplicate of your question.

Comment: If your question is really how to use [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) then please [edit] your question to reflect that. If that is your question, please explain what it is about the documentation for that method which you don't understand.

Comment: @Michael: *"no string exists I expect null if exists I expect true"* Why would you want `null` rather than `false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` (added in ES2015, aka "ES6") expects a function predicate. You're looking for `indexOf`:

```
var res = arr.indexOf(str);
```

...which finds things by comparing them with `===`. You'll get -1 if it's not found, or its index if it is.

In a comment you've said:

> no string exists I expect null if exists I expect true

...which seems a bit odd (I'd think you'd want `true` or `false`), but this will give you that:

```
var res = arr.indexOf(str) != -1 || null;
```

...because of JavaScript's [curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) *(that's a post on my blog)*.

---

Just for completeness about `find`:

But you *can* use `find`; ES5 version (in case you're polyfilling but not transpiling):

```
var res = arr.find(function(entry) { return entry === str; });
```

or in ES2015:

```
let res = arr.find(entry => entry === str);
```

`res` will be `null` if it was not found, `str` if it was. But then, you already have `str`, so... :-) `find` is more useful when you're searching for, say, an object by a property value.

Comment: *"**or** in ES2015"* - But you already said that `.find()` is an ES2015 method...

Comment: @nnnnnn: Yes, but it can trivially be polyfilled. I was polyfilling it for fully a year before I started transpiling.

Comment: Fair enough. As always you've covered everything well (though I also upvoted the answer that suggested `.includes()`, because the OP commented above that their desired result is `true` if the item exists and `null` if it doesn't).

Comment: @nnnnnn: I did too. I don't see that in the question (and `includes` doesn't return `null` if the item isn't in the array).

Answer (score 5):

Try using [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf): it's more widely supported and you can get the same results.

```
var index = arr.indexOf(str);
if(index != -1) {
  console.log("found");
  var element = arr[index]; //element found of your array
}
```

Your problem with `find` function it's probably due to it's compatibility:

[image]

As you can see, the chance you are using an incompatible browser it's not so far.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to use simple `indexOf` method. Just check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```
var array = [2, 9, 9];
array.indexOf(2);     // 0
array.indexOf(7);     // -1
array.indexOf(9, 2);  // 2
array.indexOf(2, -1); // -1
array.indexOf(2, -3); // 0
```

Answer (score 2):

`.find` method of array prototype expects on input function callback, not string you are looking for.

```
var res = arr.find(function (element) {
  return element === str;
};
```

Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/find).

Answer (score 2):

Try using `includes`

```
var foo = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'];
console.log(foo.includes('aaa'));
console.log(foo.includes('ddd'));
```

output

```
true
false
```

**Note:** `Array#includes` wasn't added until ES2016 (in June 2016), so you need a polyfill/shim for even *slightly* out of date browsers (which is simple, there's one on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)).

Comment: Good point, `includes` is a good fit for the "does it exist" use case. But it's important to note that `includes` wasn't added until June 2016 (e.g., just over two months ago), so you need a polyfill/shim (which is trivial) for even *slightly* out of date browsers.

Comment: Or `foo.includes('aaa') || null` to get the `true` or `null` result that the OP mentioned in a comment.