# how to check whether a string is part of an array string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

//for example

```
var str='i like JavaScript'
   var str1='lik';
   var abc=str.indexof(str1)
```

//abc returns 0 as 'lik' is present in 'i like JavaScript'
//like wise say i have an array

```
var arrStr=['lik','something','hi']
   var abc=str.indexof(arrStr)
```

//(this is not correct but i want to know something like this)
//abc should return 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find if an array contains a specific string in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116474/how-to-find-if-an-array-contains-a-specific-string-in-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```
let str = 'i like JavaScript'
let res = str.split(" ")
let abc = res.indexOf('like')
```

Comment: hi thanq for ur rply bt i need to find in an array nt in string

Comment: So what is wrong with your example? indexOf also works for arrays : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf