# How to check if any word inside a text is in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given a whole text like:

```
var nation = "Piazza delle Medaglie d'Oro
40121 Bologna
Italy"
```

And a given array like:

```
 ["Afghanistan", "Italy", "Albania", "United Arab Emirates"]
```

How can we check that the word ***Italy*** within that whole text is in the `array`?

Following this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6116511/1018804) this is what I tried, but I get `False` while instead ***Italy*** is present within the `array`

```
  var countries = [];
  $("#usp-custom-3 option").each(function() {
    var single = $(this).text();
    countries.push(single);
    var foundPresent = countries.includes("Piazza delle Medaglie d'Oro 40121 Bologna Italy");
    console.log(foundPresent); 
  });
```

[JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/pz3ce0o6/190/)

Comment: [Let me Google it for you?](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

Comment: yeah ok ok, it happened, easy guys. My question is edited now

Comment: Put on hold haha - Bit of a joke really, solid question - with code, and attempts. Also good answers. Some are on a power trip.

Comment: @tez simply vote to reopen... May the majority win ;)

Comment: incredible, on hold haha

Comment: @rob.m This is due to initial incompleteness. It will reopen in sometime. Have voted for it. :-)

Comment: @Rajesh okey dokey :) Thanks for the answers tho, really helped me on here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check whenever you push to an array, its even much simpler, just check the pushed element:

```
const text = " I like Italy";
const nations=[];

function insert(single){
 if( text.includes(single) /*may format single, e.g. .trim() etc*/){
   alert("Nation in text!");
 }
 nations.push(single);
}
```

[Run](http://jsbin.com/jobowagebo/edit?console)

---

If you still want to check the whole array everytime, a nested iteration may does it:

```
let countries = ["Afghanistan", "Italy", "Albania", "United Arab Emirates"];
const text = " I like Italy";

let countriesInText = countries.filter( word => text.includes( word ) );
//["Italy"]
```

[Run](http://jsbin.com/fiwuhofake/edit?console)

[Performance compared to Rajeshs answer](https://jsperf.com/regex-vs-filter-for-text-search)

If you just care if or if not, may use *.some()* instead of *.filter()*.

Comment: You're assuming a word in the array can't be *in* a word of the text. You can't  skip the tokenization. Which means there's no reason to check the other way round.

Comment: I actually prefer this answer, cleaner and very readable. (+1)

Comment: @Jonasw some dev's like results. Not fast, clean, readable code. I have that battle at work haha - So I end up writing code for "results" not for the latter.

Comment: @denys Seguret 1) depends on the definition of *in text* 2) because theres no need to check the whole array based on OPs edit

Comment: this one actually makes more sense to me, and since I am not great at regex and I need to be it faster and readable, I am accepting this one here. Also it uses `includes` which is what I was working on as per the code in my question

Comment: yet what is the reason we're keeping this line here `var countriesInText`.. ? Lets make this answer just straight to the point of the question without abstract examples, as the last conditional should be simply put up with the strings vars in the first bit of code, no?

Comment: @rob.m would you not want the value? == "countriesInText"

Comment: I would need to simply say "Nation in text". I mean that is the bit that says true or false and i can carry on with the rest of the code i have here

Comment: @Jonasw You can use this [JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/regex-vs-filter-for-text-search) as a reference for performance difference.

Comment: Yup. Just thought you can add it in answer for readers' reference as comment would be in collapsed state.

Answer (score 3):

Since you need to search a string with words in an array, best  option is to use a regex and use `string.match(regex)` to get the matched words.

```js
var nation = `Piazza delle Medaglie d'Oro
40121 Bologna
Italy`;
//var nation = "Piazza delle Medaglie d'Oro 40121 Bologna Italy";
var countries = ["Afghanistan", "Italy", "Albania", "United Arab Emirates"];
var regex = new RegExp(countries.join("|"), "i");
console.log(nation.match(regex))
```

Comment: oh this is so elegant actually, i never think of using a regex, can't get my head around them but looks so nice here

Comment: @rob.m  the text you shown,have new lines.? Isn't it?

Comment: @rob.m Glad I could help. Remember, a well constructed question will always attract better solutions as the problem statement is well defined. Showing effort/code will also help users in pointing improvements/ good practices. So if possible, share them.

Comment: @AlivetoDie yes it does have them indeed :(

Comment: @Rajesh will do man, usually do it just had a quick hit on the send button, thanks man

Comment: @Rajesh Where is `m` flag ?

Comment: Guys I have not updated anything yet. `Alive to Die` made the string multiline but there was no need to use `m` flag. I'll update in sometime. Sorry for delay. Trying to come up with a testable use-case

Comment: I don't think there is a need for any flags. This will work

Comment: can we have a conditional on here? `If match than say YEAH`?

Comment: `if(nation.match(regex)) {
       console.log("yeah");
      }`

Comment: @rob.m You can do `var matches =nation.match(regex); if(matches!=null && matches.length > 0) { ...}` or just `matches != null` will also suffice as it will return `null` if no match is found.

Answer (score 0):

```
var nation = "Piazza delle Medaglie d'Oro 40121 Bologna Italy";
searchStringInArray("Italy", nation);
function searchStringInArray (str, strArray) {
    for (var j=0; j<strArray.length; j++) {
        if (strArray[j].match(str)) return j;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this script will compare every word from var nation with all elements of array that you provided. I hope that this will solve your issue

```
<script>
    var nation = "Piazza delle Medaglie d'Oro 40121 Bologna Italy";
    test = nation.split(" ");
    array = ["Afghanistan", "Italy", "Albania", "United Arab Emirates"];
    test.forEach(function (element) {
        array.forEach(function (array_to_compare) {
            if (element == array_to_compare)
                alert("We found that word " + element + " matches in array");
        });
    }, this);
    each()

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {

    try {
        var nation = "Piazza delle Medaglie d'Oro 40121 Bologna Italy";

        var I = ["Afghanistan", "Italy", "Albania", "United Arab Emirates"]

        for (var index = 0; index < I.length; index++) {
            if (nation.toString().toUpperCase().indexOf(I[index].toString().toUpperCase()) >= 0) {
                console.log(I[index].toString());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

try this one.