# Determine if a string contains a substring within an array [NODEJS]

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, substring

I am attempting to create a search function which should be able to find multiple file types given various search parameters.

For example i'd like to feed my application the following filter array ['.ini', '.exe', 'dsak_'] and compare each file found against that array to determine if the filename includes one of those strings

Currently I am using the following code

```js
for(var i = 0; i < filter.length; i++){
  if(file.includes(filter[i])) results.push(file);
}
```

But I was hoping to see if there was a better way to achieve this?

Comment: It will be easy with regular expressions.

Comment: array.join("|") then do regex .match, but the performance stays the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45372093/how-to-check-if-any-word-inside-a-text-is-in-array/45372164#45372164

Comment: Has the performance difference been tested? I'd assume with regex that it'd have a slight advantage in larger cycles.

Comment: @user1893706 refer to the snippet rajesh provided ( and ive included to my answer there)

Comment: Better in what way? Speed to completion? Less memory use? Too many possible correct answers here.

Comment: I apologize Mike, I was referring to speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) can help you find any files that match at least one filter and [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) will ensure that you stop once the first matching filter is found:

```
var matchingFiles = files.filter(file => filters.some(filter => file.includes(filter)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the following code:

```
files.filter((file) => 
    // apply filters on files to check if it matches
     filters.some((filter) => file.includes(filter))       
)
```

Comment: Yes, find is better than reduce in this case.

Comment: Thanks @Jonasw, I get it now.