# Avoid multi indexOf in a filter loop

Tags: javascript, indexof

I need to check if a string has any indexOf of a few values. I would like to avoid things like this:

```
  let filter = tasks.filter(
    x =>
      x.eventData.workflow_name === brand &&
      (x.eventData.task_queue_name.indexOf('Value1') == -1 &&
        x.eventData.task_queue_name.indexOf('_Value2') == -1 &&
        x.eventData.task_queue_name.indexOf('Value3') == -1 &&
        x.eventData.task_queue_name.indexOf('BANG_Value4') == -1)
  )
```

I was trying to create an array like `const VALUES_TO_SKIP = ['Value1', ...]` and write indexOf condition in a single line.

Is possible to avoid a bunch of `value.indexOf(...)`?

Comment: You can do it similarly to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116474/how-to-find-if-an-array-contains-a-specific-string-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: What is `task_queue_name`? Both strings and arrays have `indexOf`. I assumed it was a string, but I see most other people are assuming it's an array. You did say "a string" though...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's a string. I want to check if has a partial value from `VALUES_TO_SKIP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was trying to create an array like `const VALUES_TO_SKIP = ['Value1', ...]` and write `indexOf` condition in a single line.

I'd use a regular expression with an alternation and `test` instead:

```
let filter = tasks.filter(x =>
    x.eventData.workflow_name === brand && !/Value1|_Value2|Value3|BANG_Value4/.test(x.eventData.task_queue_name)
);
```

Live Example:

```js
const tasks = [
    {
        eventData: {
            workflow_name: 'foo',
            task_queue_name: 'xxx BANG_Value4 yyy',
        }
    },
    {
        eventData: {
            workflow_name: 'foo',
            task_queue_name: 'none of them',
        }
    },
    {
        eventData: {
            workflow_name: 'bar',
            task_queue_name: 'Dogs loves BANG_Value4',
        }
    },
    {
        eventData: {
            workflow_name: 'foo',
            task_queue_name: 'none of them again',
        }
    },
    {
        eventData: {
            workflow_name: 'foo',
            task_queue_name: '_Value2 yyy',
        }
    }
];

const brand = "foo";

let filter = tasks.filter(x =>
    x.eventData.workflow_name === brand && !/Value1|_Value2|Value3|BANG_Value4/.test(x.eventData.task_queue_name)
);

console.log(filter);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `Array.some` or `Array.every` like :

```js
// The values to Test out
const arrayOfValue = [
  'Value1',
  '_Value2',
  'Value3',
  'BANG_Value4',
];

// Your data to filters
const tasks = [{
  eventData: {
    workflow_name: 'brand',
    task_queue_name: 'BANG_Value3 and Value2 and Value3',
  },
}, {
  eventData: {
    workflow_name: 'brand',
    task_queue_name: 'Dogs loves cat',
  },
}, {
  eventData: {
    workflow_name: 'brand',
    task_queue_name: 'Dogs loves BANG_Value4',
  },
}];

const brand = 'brand';

const filtered = tasks.filter(x =>
  x.eventData.workflow_name === brand &&
  !arrayOfValue.some(y => x.eventData.task_queue_name.includes(y))
);

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Just FWIW, `!some` is `every` (and `!every` is `some`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right, I guess it's just that I'm used to `Array.some`. It's a good comment for people coming in here

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `every` to check multiple keys and `includes` in favor of indexOf:

```
 ['Value1', '_Value2', 'Value3'].every(key =>
   !x.eventData.task_queue_name.includes(key))
```