# Finding a string in an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array of strings (names) such as:

```
name =["John Doe","Lutfur Kabir", "Moshiur Imtiaz Rahman", "Clark Kent","Jenny Doe"]
```

I want to get the index/es of the name that has Doe in it. How do I go about doing it using JavaScript.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.includes`:

[Find the previous answer here already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116474/how-to-find-if-an-array-contains-a-specific-string-in-javascript-jquery)

```html
var categoriesPresent = ['word', 'word', 'specialword', 'word'];
var categoriesNotPresent = ['word', 'word', 'word'];

var foundPresent = categoriesPresent.includes('specialword');
var foundNotPresent = categoriesNotPresent.includes('specialword');

console.log(foundPresent, foundNotPresent); // true false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create an array having indexes of strings containing the desired string:

```js
let data =["John Doe","Lutfur Kabir", "Moshiur Imtiaz Rahman", "Clark Kent","Jenny Doe"];

let result = data.reduce((r, c, i) => {
  if(c.includes('Doe')) { r.push(i); }
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```