# How to check if an HTMLCollection contains an element with a given class name using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hi i am new to programming and i want to access the array inside an object using javascript...

i have the datastructure like below,

```
const some_obj = {
    accessKey: "",
    children: [
        div.someclassname,
        div.someclassname,
        div.someclassname.highlight,
    ]
}
```

Below is what it looks like in browser console when i log the variable.

```
object
current: div.wrapper
    accessKey: ""
    align: ""
    childElementCount: 4
    childNodes: NodeList(4) [div.someclassname, div.someclassname.highlight, 
    div.someclassname]
    children: HTMLCollection(4) [div.someclassname, 
    div.someclassname.highlight, div.someclassname]
```

printing some_obj.children in the console gives below output.
    object.children 
    HTMLCollection(3)
    0: div.someclassname
    1: div.someclassname.highlight
    2: div.someclassname

Now from the some_obj i want to check if some_obj has div.classname.highlight in children array. how can i do it.

i tried using
    some_obj.current.children.find() but says find is not a function.

how can i check if the some_obj children has the div.someclassname.highlight. could someone help me fix this.thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find if an array contains a specific string in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116474/how-to-find-if-an-array-contains-a-specific-string-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Hi, is `div.classname.highlight` a string?

Comment: from the output in console  it is a htmlcollection. i think it is not a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t think there is a more elegant solution for `HTMLCollection`, but this works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style>
      .selected {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li class="test">One</li>
      <li class="test">two</li>
      <li class="test selected">Three</li>
    </ul>
    <script>
      var find = function(className) {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
        var elementsArray = [].slice.call(elements);
        for (var index = 0; index < elementsArray.length; index++) {
          var element = elementsArray[index];
          if (element.className.indexOf(className) !== -1) {
            return true;
            // return element; // If you wish to return the element instead of true (comment out previous line if this option is used)
          }
        }
        return false;
        // return null; // If you wish to return null instead of false (comment out previous line if this option is used)
      }
      console.log(find('selected'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: for some strange reason it says indexOf is not a function.

Comment: Can you please paste the output of `console.log(some_obj, some_obj.children)` in your question?

Comment: If this is what you are looking for, I would recommend changing the title to `How to check if an HTMLCollection object contains an element with a given class name`.

Comment: I see you updated the title. Did the above snippet work? Just added IE support.

Comment: thanks how do i return the element that contains the test selected classname instead of true.

Comment: `[].slice.call(elements)[0]` results in `undefined`, but `elements` is an HtmlCollection and has elements.

Answer (score 7):

Since the children are not simple `Array` but [**HTMLCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), what should be looked at is: `Array.from(NodeList)`.

So let say we want to find if an element `div.someclassname.highlight` exists on the `children` or not (testing for class name `someclassname` & `highlight`).

```
let childrenNodeArr = Array.from(some_obj.children);
/*or with spread operator [...some_obj.children]*/
/*each element is a dom node we can run classList.contains*/
const elemFound = childrenNodeArr.find(
  e =>
    e.classList.contains("someclassname") && e.classList.contains("highlight")
);

if (elemFound) {
  /*yes a div.someclassname.highlight*/
}
```

**NOTE:** The above test would pass for any dom element with class names `someclassname` & `highlight` not just the `div`. [Element.classList.contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: Note: `Array.from` doesn’t work in IE and older browsers. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @sunknudsen Yep I know +1. IE could be the only caveat. Rest of the broswers support is pretty much there, unless somebody is on like really old version. For example: Chrome 45 came in `2015`

Comment: thanks for the answer. since i wanted it to support all browsers i accepted the other one. but this works as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for some_obj.children.includes(someClass).

See [includes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp).

Comment: doesnt work either. i shall update my question with the datastructure again.