# checkboxGroupInput with options for each tick (multiple possible ticks)

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyapps

I am very new in Shiny and I am sorry if my question seems obvious. I would be very grateful for any help on the matter.

I use `checkboxGroupInput` with multiple choice (e.g. days of week) and I need options to appear for each tick (e. g. hours).

I tried to add `conditionalPanel` for each option. But this only works if only one box is ticked. If two or more boxes are ticked, no option is shown.
Moreover the conditional options appear at the bottom of all the `checkboxGroupInput` block.

Ideally, I would like the options of `checkboxGroupInput` to appear vertically (wihich is the default) and for each ticked option, a `selectInput` (or equivalently a `checkboxGroupInput`) appears on the right side of the ticked option with the conditional value.

I hope my question is clear enough and that it is not too difficult to implement!

Thanks a lot for any help :-)

```
shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Week and time"),
    div(
      id = "form",
      checkboxGroupInput("days", "Days of week",
                  c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wenesday")),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.days == 'Monday'",
                       selectInput("time",
                                   "Hours to choose Monday", 
                                   c("8h00", "9h00"))),
      conditionalPanel(condition = "input.days == 'Tuesday'",
                       selectInput("time",
                                   "Hours to choose Tuesday", 
                                   c("8h00", "9h00"))),
      actionButton("submit", "Submit", class = "btn-primary")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
  }
)
```

Comment: Did the answer help you by any chance? If so, please mark it as accepted that the community is aware of it. Otherwise, point to what is missing. Thanks!

Comment: @mnist I tried the code, but the result was not  exactly what I expected... Anyway, I know how it is hard to get points on SO!

Comment: whatv has been missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You nest two question together here. regarding the first one ("How to check whether the `radioButton` is clicked"), it is a pure JavaScript problem. I took the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15276975/8107362).

About the alignment: This is trickier. I show you a simple approach that just has two `conditionalPanels` with approx. the same vertical space so the other objects do not jump up and down. If you want complete control over this, rather go with single checkboxes. Have a checkbox and the `selectInput` in one row. In the server, you can have them in `reactiveValues`, for example.

Depends on you code structure which is more difficult to implement

```
shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Week and time"),
    fluidRow(column(
      id = "form",
      width = 3,
      checkboxGroupInput("days", "Days of week",
                         c(HTML("Monday"), "Tuesday", "Wenesday"))),
      column(width = 9,
             # check whether Monday is in input.days
             conditionalPanel(condition = "input.days.indexOf('Monday') > -1",
                              selectInput("time",
                                          "Hours to choose Monday", 
                                          c("8h00", "9h00"))),
             # if Monday is not in input.days, show a div with the same size as the
             # selectInput
             conditionalPanel(condition = "input.days.indexOf('Monday') == -1",
                              div(style = "height:70px")),
             # check whether Tuesday is in input.days
             conditionalPanel(condition = "input.days.indexOf('Tuesday') > -1",
                              selectInput("time",
                                          "Hours to choose Tuesday", 
                                          c("8h00", "9h00"))),
             # if Tuesday is not in input.days, show a div with the same size as the
             # selectInput
             conditionalPanel(condition = "input.days.indexOf('Tuesday') == -1",
                              div(style = "height:70px"))
      )),
    fluidRow(actionButton("submit", "Submit", class = "btn-primary"))

  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
  }
)
```